# How to disable Decoding encoded XML Special characters in Java using DOM parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am storing XML file in DB as string format, before storing in DB i am making sure that the document is well formed and converting all special characters `<`,`>`,`&`,`"`,`'` to `&lt;` `&gt;` etc.,

when i get the string data back form DB and converting the String to XML document using DOM Parser, but when i convert these encoded special characters (`&lt;` `&gt;` etc.) are being converted back to actual characters (`<`,`>`).

But I don't want this automatic decoding that making by DOM parser, i just want the same encoded characters as it is.

How do i avoid this decoding happening form DOM parser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the entities, e.g. `&lt;`, in the XML returned from the database before parsing it?  For example:

```
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.replaceAll("&", "&amp;"))));
```

Comment: The String is having all the special characters in the form on encoded form only, < is in &lt; and > in &gt; and & is in &amp;, then moment when i try to convert string to Document then these encoded characters being converted to actual characters like &lt; is converted to <

Comment: It's working for me.  Are you able to show an example of your code that's not working right?  E.g., `"<test>Some text with entities: &lt; &gt;</test>".replaceAll("&", "&amp;")`

Comment: For me to help you further, please provide a code example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is my Example calss

Comment: "<Section DisplayLocation=\"Middle\" TargetLocation=\"ufdLocation0\" TemplateFileName=\"formaol\" TemplateID=\"formaol\" TemplateName=\"Form AOL\" UFDID=\"2a3935c7-105d-470e-b8ab-ad90c8f44880\"><Inputs BusinessNamePP=\"&lt;&gt;&lt;&gt;\" Caption=\"\" Description=\"A line must be active on your account for at least 30 days before it can be transferred to a new account.You have &lt;?ufd 'Test'?&gt; days remaining before you can transfer.\" Image1=\"\" Image2=\"\" ImageLabel1=\"\" ImageLabel2=\"\" emailPP=\"&lt;Anji&gt;\" firstNamePP=\"&lt;Jeera&gt;\" lastNamePP=\"&lt;Hellow&gt;\"/></Section>";

Comment: {
  Document doc = null;
  try {
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = null;
   db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XMLdata)));
   if (doc != null) {
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Inputs");
          for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
              System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Description").getNodeValue());
          }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
 }

Comment: This is the output:::A line must be active on your account for at least 30 days before it can be transferred to a new account.You have <?ufd 'Test'?> days remaining before you can transfer.

Comment: Here if you see in output the decoding happened already i don't want that to be happening, i am expecting "A line must be active on your account for at least 30 days before it can be transferred to a new account.You have &lt;?ufd 'Test'?&gt; days remaining before you can transfer" without decoding by DOM parser

Comment: Sorry the comment is not allowing me more characters so added in separate comments  please help

Comment: I have created another question that will have all the info. this is the link::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769619/disable-automatic-decoding-by-xml-dom-parser-in-java